# How to implement Notification On or Notification OFF for Urban AirShip?

Tags: android

I am developing an android application,In my application using Urban Airship for Push notification.It is working fine,I want to if i click on "Notification On" in UI,I will receive Notification  to my device,when i click "Notification OFF" in my UI,I will not receive notification to my device.How to implement the code in Urban Airship?How is possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

to enable it

```
PushManager.enablePush();
```

and to disable it

```
PushManager.disablePush();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your button Click, put this code:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        final ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(
                "com.urbanairship.airmail",
                "com.urbanairship.airmail.MainListActivity");
        intent.setComponent(cn);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Followed by this in your manifest file put this in your `<application Tag>`:

```
android:name=".QuadDealsPushReceiver"
```

Create a  QuadDealsPushReceiver.class and put this code:

```
package com.fsp.quaddeals;

import com.urbanairship.push.APIDReceiver;
import com.urbanairship.push.AirMail;
import com.urbanairship.push.PushReceiver;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class QuadDealsPushReceiver extends Application {
    public void onCreate(){
        AirMail am = AirMail.getInstance();
        am.acceptPush(this, new PushReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(String message, String payload){
                Log.d("push", "Got message '" + message +"' and payload '" + payload + "'");
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(String message, String payload){
                Log.d("push", "User clicked the notification, got message and payload: "
                        + message + ", " + payload);
                /* In this example, we fire up our MainActivity class when the
                 * user clicks the Status Bar Notification. Note that we *must*
                 * use the flag Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK to start a new
                 * activity because this callback is fired from within a
                 * BroadcastReceiver.
                 **/
                Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
                intent.setClass(QuadDealsPushReceiver.this, SplashMain.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                QuadDealsPushReceiver.this.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        am.setAPIDReceiver(this, new APIDReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(String apid, boolean valid){
                if(valid){
                    Log.d("push", "Got apid: " + apid);
                } else {
                    Log.d("push", "Application registration invalid!"+ apid);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onAirMailInstallRefusal() {
                QuadMain.register = false;
                Log.d("push", "AirMail Install Refused!");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

For further clarification use this link:

[Help for Push notification](http://www.urbanairship.com)